# wsl terminal has no scroll

Tags: scrolling

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 in Windows Subsystem Linux.
But it suddenly stopped me from scrolling up and down.

For example, when you want to know how the command `tar` works so you type `tar --help`, the result is so long that you should scroll up and down to read all of what it says.

But when I type `tar --help`, the result only shows that is permitted in current size of the terminal, so I can never read the upper part, only the last part. Scroll doesn't appear. How can I fix it?

Comment: Use a *pager* e.g. `tar --help | less`

Comment: Now I can read the whole text but I want to know how to get my scroll back...Because I can't even properly use 'ls'!

Comment: I ran both 'tput rmcup' and 'tput reset' and all didn't work..

Answer (score 11):

What helped me was clicking on the opened WSL window properties, in the Layout tab, in Screen Buffer Size, setting Height 9999 (maximum allowed), with the option "Wrap text output on screen" checked:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, thanks Jean!

Comment: Oh wow.  All this time I had been thinking "Command History" under the Options tab was where scrollback was set, and was wondering why everyone else could go up to 9999 whereas I could only get it to 999.  Just noticed this is the *Layout* tab.